# How to pass multiple inputs to a GET request in karate

Tags: karate

Thank you very much for the solution to my previous question. I have another request here below:
I need to validate a response of my previous POST call using a GET operation.
I have a GET method that requires multiple inputs to pass in the request. Below is the way I am doing:

Get call: "/Questions/Get/"
Inputs: formType, pageId, sectionId, name

My code in karate:
*First approach**

```
Given path "/Questions/Get/",formType,pageId,sectionId,name
When method GET
Then status 200
```

**Second Approach:**

```
Given path "/Questions/Get/"
And param formType = formtype
And param pageId = pageid
And param sectionId = sectionid
And param name = questionname
When method GET
Then status 200
```

**Third approach:**

```
* def getreq =
"""
{
 "formType":"#(formtype)", 
 "pageId":"#(pageid)", 
 "sectionId":"#(sectionid)", 
 "shortName":"#(questionname)"
 }
 """
 Given path "/Questions/Get/",getreq 
 When method GET
 Then status 200
```

In all the cases above, I see failed request.
Kindly help me to know if this is the right approach or something is missing here..

Answer (score 0):

You need to be clear about what you mean by "multiple inputs". Is it query parameters or path parameters. A body is not an option for a `GET`. Please spend some time reading the docs and understanding the different types of API requests.

So no one can help you unless they know what your server is expecting. Take a look at the below example, try executing it, change the values and see the difference.

```
* url 'https://httpbin.org'
* param foo = 'bar'
* path 'anything'
* request { foo: 'bar' }
* method post
```